# Facebook Access Token is Expired using Facebook SDK PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am trying to link my application to a `facebook` user account but every time I go through the process of retrieving their profile I get this error:

```
string(140) "{
"error":{
  "message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
  "type":"OAuthException",
  "code":2500
  }
}"
```

The reason I am confused is that when I initially request an `access_token` from `facebook` it return a token for me.

```
string(56) "access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}"
```

Which I am then told is expired and I don't know why.....

I understand in order to get an access token you must follow a particular workflow.

1. Client Requests access and permissions via SDK and Login Dialog.
2. User Authenticates and approves permissions
3. Access token returned to client
4. Graph API calls with short-term access token (web) or long-term access token (native mobile)

Based on what I've seen in my code, I get to step 3 but step 4 fails because the token is said to be expired. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this!?

I notice that for step 1 the login dialog is never shown but I still get an access code returned despite this. Could that be something to do with it? This is the way I perform step 1.

```
<a class="lists" href="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=564083793722908&redirect_uri=<?=urlencode($facebook_callback_url)?>&scope=offline_access,publish_stream,status_update">Connect a Facebook account</a>
```

Step 2. never seems to occur

Step 3. An access token is returned though. See above.

Step 4. Fails with the above error of expiration.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot request user information with an app access token. You need a usser access token to do that. Your Login process needs to adhere the docs at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1#login

to get a user access token. Apparantly, this is not the case with your code.

Furthermore, you're only using permissions which are (long) deprecated. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#adding
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference

Comment: Those links were a huge help, it's working now. Thank you very much.